# Is it possible to hide chrome's statusbar?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, parameters

I'm developing a web application for my company. I plan to use a [chrome application shortcut](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en) so it looks less like a website and more like an application.

But even in an application shortcut, there is still a status bar (at the bottom) telling everyone the URL. I want to turn it off. Can I?

The best option would be a flag on the extension like

```
 C:/Program Files... chrome.exe --no-statusbar
```

I could also settle for a chrome extension. Is there one?

An answer short of compiling my own statusbar-less version of Chrome would be good.

Comment: Are you talking confusing the status bar about the **address bar**?  The status bar is at the bottom of the window.  The address bar is at the top.  **You generally cannot remove the address bar for security reasons.**  When this was possible in the past, unscrupulous people realized they could hide the address bar, and then include a forged one for phishing/scamming purposes.

Comment: @Zoredache The address bar can be removed by making an application shortcut. That is not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about the status bar in the footer. Amending question for clarity.

Comment: Known command-line switches are here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/